# How to correct Warning : array subscript has type 'char' [-Wchar-subscripts]

Tags: c++, atmel-studio

Hi I write a function to reset a `Character Array` in *Atmel studio* as below:

```
char PacketData[50];
void Reset(){
        for (char i=0; i<=50;i++)
           PacketData[i]='\0';
    };
```

But Always get warning when compile the program:

> Warning       array subscript has type 'char' [-Wchar-subscripts]

Anybody know how I remove this warning?

Comment: Just declare i as an int. There is no reason for it to be a char.

Comment: for (int i=o; i<= 50; i++)

However, this is a bug. Because you are accessing the array beyond the end of the array.

Comment: The normal way to do it is: 
for (int i=0; i<50; i++)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a general programming question. It would fit better on StackOverflow, but they'd also expect you to research what the warning means and the hint "-Wchar-subscripts" yourself. Both things excellently googleable!

Comment: @mkeith :I use char because i dont need to a variable with size of `int`, my idea is when need a small range its better to use `char` that allocate 1 byte of memory

Comment: @MarcusMüller I know but in other IDE its have other approach that in atmel studio , for example Intel c++ 11 have a big IDE with big Resource. its too clear that atmel studio is too different as Intel c++ IDE(for example)

Comment: @combo_ci you're pretty much wrong in that aspect. It's really nothing specific about compilers for small devices. The GCC emits that and similar warnings for *all* platforms, be it intel/x86 or AVR, simply because it's a warning generated by the C *frontend*, not by the machine-specific backend. Anyway, general programming question, not electronics-related, off-topic.

Comment: @MarcusMüller In generally you right..but I strat coding for avr from 6 month ago and coding c++ on x86 platform for 10 years ago..may be a wrong guide about use smaller size variable cues to i use `char` instead of `int` , but the _Tom_ guide solve the problem, use `unsigned char i`, BTW thanks for attention Marcuse..Good Luck

Comment: Well, I'm well aware of that warning on x86 and I'm not new to coding myself, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning is fairly self explanatory. One of your array subscripts is a char.

Specifically:

```
for (char i=0 ...
     PacketData[i] = ...
```

Notice how `i`, your array subscript (index), is a `char` type.

The reason this is bad is that chars are often unexpectedly signed which means you can end up with negative subscripts if you don't realise that - i.e. if you didn't realise it was signed, instead of accessing index `[128]`, you would be inadvertently accessing index `[-128]`.

You should be able to fix the warning by simply replacing `char i` with `unsigned char i` if working on an 8-bit processor. For a 32bit processor, you are better off using an `unsigned int` as it will be much more efficient.

Alternatively, given your code doesn't ever set `i` to be negative, simply ignore the warning. However make sure you check your for loop conditions. Arrays are 0-indexed, meaning an array declared with a size of `[50]` has elements numbered 0 through to 49. Your for loop does `i <= 50` which means it will try to access a non-existent element index 50. You should change that to `i < 50`.

---

As a sidenote, why reinvent the wheel:

```
memset(PacketData, '\0', sizeof(PacketData)/sizeof(PacketData[0]))
```

Comment: As a side note, why `'\0'` when `0` would do. :-)

Comment: @Andrew true it's the same but I like to use '\0' when chars are involved to differentiate from doing it to an integer array.

Comment: about `memset`, I trying to use native future instead of add library to my program to avoid increase size of output file

Comment: @combo_ci for an 8-bit AVR using avr-libc, `memset` is a highly optimised standard function.